# How do I get permissions to run WireShark in Kali Linux AWS?

Tags: kali-linux

I have a Kali Linux instance in AWS. I login via SSH using a key-pair file with ec2-user. I've configured VNC server for GUI access and I can connect.

However, whenever I try to run Wireshark, I'm presented with a box "Authentication is required to run /usr/bin/wireshark" as root. I have 2 options
Debian (ec2-user)
Kali

Debian doesn't have a password associated as AWS uses a key-pair and I've set the Kali password, but that doesn't load WireShark.

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/default-credentials/ is typically what you should consider. That being said, the `ssh_key` may not be established for a variety of reasons.

Assuming current ssh/vnc have enough privilege to do this, run

```
sudo passwd kali
```

If you do not, I would recommend setting the password for kali in the user data script when you fire up the server.